# gstreamer input-selector is unable to stream gapless video for rtspsrc element.

Tags: gstreamer

I have 5 ip cameras (all are rtspsrc element) and one audio src (rtspsrc)

All 5 ip cameras are connected with input-selector element and it switched from one camera to another camera.

My code works perfectly fine [1] : http://hastebin.com/raw/adatujewes

But there is one flaw in streaming. I am seeing a pause for 1 second whenever input-selector is switching between camera.

Look at timestamp 1min 12sec on my streaming video url which is using my binary generated from code [1]:

[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPlN_3YhmrM

You will see cameras are switched every 5 seconds after 1:12 on that url [2]  However, there is a pause of 1 second when camera switching happens,

I tried with changing delay of queue/ replacing queue with queue2/ making rtspsec latency=0  .

But nothing helps me . I am kind of stuck.

Can anyone please help me ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What is the shift element in your code? Also don't use queue2 but queue, and sync-mode=1 on the input-selector could help. But overall you'll have to check where exactly the 1 second pause comes from, if the problem is for example that the input-selector is not synchronizing correctly and already forwarded one more second of data than what is "current" at this point. Or if the problem is a missing keyframe (try decoding before the input-selector to prevent that or try the cache-buffers property), or ...

Comment: Shift [1] element is shifting ip camera video buffers by +550ms .It is only for lip sync purpose between audio and video .  It is not generating any additional delay.

Comment: Shift [1] element is shifting ip camera video buffers by +550ms .It is only for lip sync purpose between audio and video .  It is not generating any additional delay.                                                                                                            I tried with queue2 and sync-mode=1 but it didn't help me and I stil  see 1 second pause  . I also tried with cache-buffers property of input-selector but i still see same issue.  [1] http://gentrans.sourceforge.net/docs/head/gst-entrans-plugins/html/gst-entrans-plugins-shift.html

Comment: My guess is that input selector needs to wait for keyframe from rtsp source and it should change rtspsrc at that particular point which it is not doing. Correct me if I am wrong.  This may be a bug in input-selector

Comment: A bug is filed on https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759470